# How to generate random numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random numbers in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript)

Hi..

I want to generate random numbers (integers) in javascript within a specified range. ie. 101-999. How can I do that. Does Math.random() function supports range parameters ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript) It covers exactly your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function below takes a min and max value (your range).

```
function randomXToY(minVal,maxVal)
{
  var randVal = minVal+(Math.random()*(maxVal-minVal));
  return Math.round(randVal);
}
```

Use:

```
var random = randomXToY(101, 999);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Just scale the result:

```
function randomInRange(from, to) {
  var r = Math.random();
  return Math.floor(r * (to - from) + from);
}
```

Comment: Great...Works pretty well...Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*898)+101
```